# How can i pass a control object between a vb6 exe and .net dll?

Tags: .net, dll, vb6, exe

We are planning phased migration of a vb6 project to vb.net.
Hence we want to refer some objects in our vb6 EXE like textbox, msflexgrid from vb.net DLL.

Someone has mention in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/380f15ff-ac61-42d8-9576-7d3407e054ec/passing-vbnet-control-class-object-to-vb6-control-object?forum=vbinterop) that it's not possible (You can't pass the managed object to VB6)

Is it possible?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of some other question - but here's some high level notes. You can pass a COM wrapper of a managed object to VB6, and it will look much like it would from .NET. Depending on the source of the object there may or may not be a COM wrapper already, or you may or may not be able to create one. If you can provide more details of the control itself that would help. Even if you can't wrap the object itself for some reason, you might be able to pass an object which serves as a proxy.

Comment: The following may have the information you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459250/can-net-custom-controls-be-used-in-vb6-form, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346620/making-a-dll-com-accessible,

Comment: @DaveInCaz  the control object to pass between vb6 exe and .net dll will be textbox,flexgrid